# iOS: Swift – Change Backgroundcolor during Flip-Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I was able to transition between two `ViewController`s, but everytime this flipping transition is called the background of the View is somehow black which doesn't match the general look of my App.

I found some Tutorials on how to get rid of this in Obj-C, but since I have no idea what that means, I was hoping that you guys could translate it to Swift for me.

Here is the website with the Obj-C-Code:
[Obj-C Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360308/background-during-modal-view-horizontal-flip-transition)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't meant for translating code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

**Swift 4 / Swift 5:**

```swift
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```